# Orbeon-forms: How to check if yes-no answer is no (not empty or no!)

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have a yes-no input and a text input and I want the text input to be required if and only if the yes-no input has the value no.

When I use `$my-yesno-control eq false()` as required-formula in my text input, then it will be required if the yes-no input is either empty or no, but I only want to catch the 'no' case. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the expression to be true if and only if users haven't selected "Yes", then use:

```
not($yes-no/string() = 'true')
```

If you're interested on knowing more about why you need to write this, see [this section of the documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas-examples.html#testing-on-a-yes-no-answer-field) which dwells into this in more details.

Comment: Actually wanted to do the opposite thing, but using `$yes-no/string() = 'false'`did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @Tagas I'm glad it worked for you, and thank you for the update.